# How to pause (terminate) extraction process in inno-setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using some external decompressors such as 7z and rar with inno-setup, but when I click to cancel button (it asks for abort or no) it doesn't pause the extraction proccess like with the original inno compressed files.

Is there any function or procedure to pause the install when I click to cancel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, when you're running an external process, Inno is essentialy locked until it returns.
If you want to be able to cancel installation, either leave it to Inno (it normally does a better job) or get the extraction utilities to show a progress and a cancel prompt.